# How properly remove an index or value in a array after deselect datatables row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a sample jQuery DataTables by selecting in a row then appending the Id's into a hidden field. Somehow once I do deselect the row the selected index or value also must remove in the value of hidden field. But it repeatedly or duplicate the Id's. How to properly implement removing a item in a array using JavaScript.

Data:

row 1: Id: 50
row 2: Id: 55
row 3: Id: 60

JS:

```
var dataTable = null;
var assignedTo = [];

 dataTable = $("#table").DataTable({ ... });

        dataTable.off("select").on("select",
            function(e, dt, type, indexes) {
                dataTable.rows('.selected').every(function(rowIndex) {

                    assignedTo.push(dataTable.row(rowIndex).data().Id);

                    $("#AssignedTo").val(JSON.stringify(assignedTo));
                });
            });

        dataTable.off("deselect").on("deselect",
            function(e, dt, type, indexes) {
                dataTable.rows({ selected: false }).every(function(rowIndex) {

                    assignedTo.splice(rowIndex, 1);

                    $("#AssignedTo").val(JSON.stringify(assignedTo));
                });
            });
```

Output: If I select row 1 and 2

value="[50, 55]"

Output: If I deselect row 2 then

value="[50]"

Output: If I deselect all row then

value="[]"

Comment: A working code snippet would really help out here =)

Comment: The same logic for selecting needs to happen for deselecting.  If the element is deselected, `dataTables.rows('.selected')` would return all the records still selected, and you can rebuild the complete array.  Do not try to remove the element from the string.  Just rebuild it

Comment: @Taplar what do you mean?

Comment: Do the exact same thing you are doing for the select logic, for the deselect logic.

Comment: @Taplar sorry it doesn't work. It just appending or multiply the Id's like this, value="[50, 55, 55]"

Comment: Make sure to set `assignedTo = []` before you start the loop, every time

Comment: @Taplar it worked, but the it remain 1 element in a array the last one example [50, 55] I remove 50 then [55] still there.

Comment: Because you are updating the value every iteration.  If there are no iterations, nothing updates.  Do not update the value until you have rebuilt the entire array

Comment: @Taplar I can't guess it what you say. Sorry, I am not familiar using this DataTables.

Comment: Read your logic.  When are you updating the value?  Inside the loop.  So if you uncheck the last option, there is nothing to loop over.  So the value update would never happen.  Which is why you need to move that val() update **outside** the loop.  So even if they uncheck them all, the value will update with your `assignedTo` array, which will be empty

Comment: @Taplar thanks I worked now.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dataTable = $("#table").DataTable({ ...
});

function rebuildAssignedToValue(e, dt, type, indexes) {
  //make a new result array each time
  var assignedTo = [];
  
  //push all the selected value to the array
  dataTable.rows('.selected').every(function(rowIndex) {
    assignedTo.push(dataTable.row(rowIndex).data().Id);
  });
  
  //update the value once
  $("#AssignedTo").val(JSON.stringify(assignedTo));
}

//reuse the common method for both events
dataTable.off("select").on("select", rebuildAssignedToValue);
dataTable.off("deselect").on("deselect", rebuildAssignedToValue);
```